# how to unzip .zip file and its sub directories

Tags: unzip

I have a zip file and in that I have multiple folders zipped.
How do I unzip all the files in one shot.

I tried unzip -r  but it didn't work

Regards,
Vikas

Comment: @stumblebee Not a duplicate of that question, because he has recursively zipped files.

Comment: @Harry `unzip`does not have a `-r` option.

Comment: @stumblebee Yes, but the question is still answerable (see my line below). I was just saying that it's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Harry I accidentally linked the wrong duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Hack solution:

```
until [ "$(find . -name '*.zip' | wc -l)" = 0 ]; do ZIP="$(find . -name '*.zip' | head -1)"; cd $(dirname "$ZIP") && unzip $(basename "$ZIP") && cd - && mv "$ZIP" "$ZIP.bak"; done
```

The quoting isn't perfect, so it might not work if you have spaces or other special characters in your directories or zipfiles.

Comment: You can use `until find . -name '*.zip' | grep -q .; do` as a simpler (probably more efficient) check. Also, you should quote all the other command substitutions `"$(dirname ...)"`, `"$(basename ...)"`, etc.